# how to open multiple files in pdfplumber?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-rename

I have multiple PDF files created with Access DB forms. The only way I can extract text from them is using pdfplumber. Here is my code and it works perfectly for just 1 file.

```
import pdfplumber

with pdfplumber.open('CS_page_1.pdf') as pdf:
    page = pdf.pages[0]
    string = page.extract_text()
    file_name = string[43:48]
    print(file_name)
```

I need to use this extracted string to rename this file and the 100 other files in the folder.
What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Use `glob` module

Comment: You can use glob (as mentioned by @Astrian_72954, and os.rename or shutil.move for the rename. Also, rememober to .close() the file before attempting to rename it

Answer (score 1):

Would first build a list of all the pdfs in your folder using glob (https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

Then iterate through each of them- pdfplumb them to obtain the desired string (which you want to rename the file to)- and then rename each individually (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_rename.htm). Something like this:

```
import glob
import pdfplumber
import os

arr_of_files = (glob.glob("/path/to/pdfs/*.pdf"))

for file in arr_of_files:
    with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
        page = pdf.pages[0]
        string = page.extract_text()
        file_name = string[43:48]
        os.rename(file, file_name)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Will do :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pdfplumber
import glob
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
for current_pdf_file in tqdm(glob.glob("<pathname>\.pdf")):
    with pdfplumber.open(current_pdf_file) as my_pdf:
         # do other things here?
```